# What collision name is supposed to be passed to contact sensor?

Tags: ros-kinetic, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor) it seems, that you are supposed to put the name of the collision tag of the link we want to detect the collision of.

When you have the model in URDF and spawn it into the gazebo world, the collision tab of the link would bear name like `<link_name>_<joint_type>_lump__<collision_tag_name>_collision`. In this answer, the author uses this name to pass to the contact sensor.

Neither of the options works for me, so I can't verify which one is right.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21992/what-collision-name-is-supposed-to-be-passed-to-contact-sensor?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is only important what is the collision tag name in the SDF description. How the Gazebo sees the model you can see by following these steps

1. Convert XACRO description to URDF

   `$ rosrun xacro xacro robot.xacro > robot.urdf`
2. Convert URDF description to SDF

   `$ gz sdf -p robot.urdf > robot.sdf`
3. Open the SDF file and find the link you want to detect the contacts of. This name goes to the contact sensor collision tags.

This sensor can be defined in xacro file of the robot as

```
<robot name="robot" xmlns:xacro="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
  <gazebo reference="my_link">
    <sensor name='my_link_contact' type='contact'>
       <always_on>1</always_on>
       <contact>
         <collision>my_link_fixed_joint_lump__my_link_collision_collision</collision>
         <topic>/my_link_contact</topic>
       </contact>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0